# Removing partitions from Chromebook (Chrome Recovery Utility not working)

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, operating-systems, google-chrome

I dual installed GalliumOS and ChromeOS on my Lenovo 100S ChromeBook.

I tried to uninstall GalliumOS but didn't manage to delete its partitions.

Now I have ChromeOS installed, but it has under 1 GB of free space because most of the Hard Drive space is taken up by these unneeded partitions.

I've tried to use the Chrome Recovery Utility to install a recovery program to an SD card and to a USB stick.

Running the recovery utility on Chrome shows an error because there is not 4GB space on the computer to download the recovery program

I tried running it on Windows as well but it also failed to install to the USB. I formatted the USB to whatever Windows wanted prior to trying to install the recovery program. The error is non-specific, it just says "utility error" or something.

Comment: Have you tried the dev mode keys? When taking it out of dev mode, Google's documentation claims that it repartitions the hard drive to it's default layout. Whether it does is a mystery, but that's worked for me 110% of the time.

Comment: Thanksgiving, Dooley labs. I fixed it by installing the recovery USB on a osx computer.

Comment: And by the way @Dooley_labs, I first tried to take it out of dev mode but this didn't fix the partition.

Comment: Then Google needs to update their documentation, @maxpleaner xD

Comment: what's new. @Dooley_labs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to install the chrome recovery to USB on osx. This fixed the partition